# How to push arrays into an associative array, and then retrieve the values for comparison?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My problem is that I want to create an array, to hold multiple arrays that I can compare with each other. This will be used for check boxes changes across multiple pages at the same time.

So for example I'd like to have:

```
masterArray = [];
masterArrayChanged = [];
```

Then to be able to do this:

```
masterArray["pageName"][ARRAY OF CHECKBOXES HERE]
masterArrayChanged["pageName"][ARRAY OF CHECKBOXES HERE ];
On user checkbox click => masterArrayChanged["pageName"].push({thisCheckBox});
```

So that later I can go and compare the two arrays to see if the user made changes:

```
jQuery.grep(masterArrayChanged["pageName"], function(el) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(el, masterArray["pageName"]) == -1) alert(el);
});
```

Any idea if this is doable? Or if there is a better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Hi Amir, there are no associate arrays in javascript. You can use an object (literal) instead: `var masterArray = {};`.

Comment: why not keep track of changes when they occur?

Comment: Through JavaScript's wonkiness, arrays are an extension of objects. Objects are the ones usually used as string-associative arrays (or "maps/dictionaries"). Fun tip: You can check `masterArray.length` and it will still be 0. You're basically instantiating a child class, but then only using the functionality of the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I answered my own question. Please correct me if this is wrong, or  if there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
  var pagename,
  masterArrayChanged= [],
  masterArray = [];



var updateFunc = function(checkBox,action,page){
      if(action === 'add') {
        masterArrayChanged[page].push({ checkBox });
      }
      else {
        masterArrayChanged[page].splice( $.inArray(checkBox, masterArrayChanged[tabID]), 1 );        
      }
      console.dir(masterArrayChanged[page]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's doable. Only thing is, comparing the arrays might end up being a bit resource intensive, especially if you'll be dealing with a lot of data.

So instead of two arrays, why not only have one array that keeps track of the changes that have happened? So on submit, you only check if there are any values in the array. If there are values, then you know changes were done by the user.

You might also want to give the check-boxes identifiers, so when a check-box (or check-box group) changes, you add it's identifier to the array/object and if the user undoes the changes, you remove the identifier